# Calling a class from another view

Tags: iphone, view

I am doing a game in iphone, suppose to change menu view to the game on touch single player.
when the view change only the interface is shown but everything is not moving. i am suspecting that my codes only manage to call the view but not the game class. Is there anything i can call with other codes that anyone can help?

-(IBAction) displayView;{
        secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
        [self.view addSubview:secondViewController.view];

```
    NSLog(@"PLAY");
```

}

This is the code that i currently using which only call the interface whereby secondViewController is the game class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if your code is being called, the easiest way to check is place a breakpoint there and see if it gets hit when you "Build & Debug".